# limsup $(n|a_{n}|)^{1/n}=$limsup $(|a_{n}|)^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have troubles proving the next result:

> \begin{equation}
> \limsup\sqrt[n]{n|a_{n}|}=\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}
> \end{equation}
>   where $a_{n}$ is a bounded sequence.

**My attempt:**
Since $\limsup(s_{n}t_{n})\leq\limsup(s_{n})\limsup(t_{n})$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$ I have the inequality $\fbox{$\leq$}$. But I can't prove the other inequality.

I will appreciate any hint, thanks.

Comment: The question in the title and body are not the same

Comment: The other one is the trivial one. Note that $n\lvert a_n\rvert\geq \lvert a_n\rvert$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelLee Yes, it was trivial haha